# Вывод данных в datagrid из разных таблиц

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, access

есть БД в нем хранятся таблицы связанны между собой, есть таблица студенты (student), группы(course) и оценки(estimation). Нужно в DATAGRID вывести столбцы по предметам, все студенты из групп и их оценки по предмету[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вывожу столбцы следующим образом

```
private void LoadColumn()
        {
            db.OpenConnection();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand($"select * from predmets where `id_course` = {group_id}", db.GetConnection());
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn()
                    {
                        Binding = new Binding("predmet_id"),
                        Header = GetPredmetId(reader.GetInt32(2)),
                        IsReadOnly = false
                    };
                    GroupDataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
                }
            }
            db.CloseConnection();
        }
```

а студентов

```
db dbase = new db();
            dbase.OpenConnection();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand($"select * from student where `course_id` = {group_id}", dbase.GetConnection());
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Grades.Add(new Grade()
                    {
                        id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        student_name = reader.GetString(2),
                        grade = GetGrade(group_id, reader.GetInt32(0), GetPredmet(group_id)),
                        predmet_id = GetPredmet(group_id)
                    });
                }
            GroupDataGrid.ItemsSource = Grades;
            dbase.CloseConnection();
```

есть Data grid

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                  Name="GroupDataGrid"
                  MaxColumnWidth="400"
                  ColumnWidth="*"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  SelectionMode="Single" 
                  Loaded="GroupDataGrid_Loaded"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding id}" Header="Id" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding student_name}" Header="ФИО" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Чисто любопытство: вы студент и вас препод так учит писать программу? Или вы сами по метаниту поучились и так сделали?

Comment: По правильному вам нужно создать класс. Один экземпляр этого класса будет одной строкой в DataGrid. В классе должны быть поля и свойства с именем студента и перечнем предметов. Дальше создаете список List<имя класса> StudentList. Или лучше observablecollection<имя класса>. И этот список заполняете результатом sql-запроса. Да, вам нужно из БД доставать инфу с помощью одного запроса, а не двух. Дальше в xaml для DataGrid устанавливаете свойство ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}"

Comment: _Тяжело вздыхает_... Опять никчёмный класс `db`. Если в процессе работы с БД возникнет исключение, ваше соединение останется в подвешенном состоянии. Выкиньте этот класс. Используйте `OleDbConnection` напрямую. При этом не забывая оборачивать его вызов в `using`. Строку соединения храните в поле. Также оберните в `using` использование `OleDbCommand`.

Comment: @alex6327 - `StudentList` - венгерская нотация не нужна. Список следует именовать во множественном числе: `students`.

Comment: @alex6327, а как мне вывести их оценки, насчет любопытство, два в одном, плохой препод и метанит или препод, который учил по метаниту. К сути вопроса, т.е. я вытяну студентов и предметы, но как вытащить оценки студентов по предметам,

Comment: тебе просто надо написать правильный SQL-запрос используя `join'ы`

Comment: @Pekor. можете написать небольшой пример?

Comment: Если ваша проблема заключается в том, как извлечь данные из нескольких таблиц, то задайте вопрос именно об этом. При этом вы должны показать структуру таблиц и свои попытки написания sql-запроса. Всё! Не должно быть ничего лишнего: не нужен код C# с ADO.NET, не нужна XAML-разметка WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю правильно ли я понял, что именно надо вывести, но сделал вот так + извиняюсь что это не access (это MSSQL), но думаю там особой разницы нет, если я не прав, то удалю ответ.

```
SELECT dbo.predmets.id_predmet, dbo.student.fullname, dbo.estimation.student_id, dbo.estimation.predmet_id, dbo.estimation.ball, dbo.predmets.id_course
FROM dbo.predmets
INNER JOIN
dbo.student ON dbo.predmets.id = dbo.student.id
INNER JOIN
dbo.estimation ON dbo.predmets.id = dbo.estimation.id
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В любом случае надеюсь пример понятен, если что задавай вопросы в комментариях, буду исправлять ответ.

И да, очень прошу тебя, не миксуй название полей на английском и русском, `fullname` и `ball`, `predmet` выглядят просто смешно и нелепо.

Comment: ну и да, сложно конечно из-за названий полей и таблиц разобраться в реляционной модели (в том правильно ли выделены сущности и их поля), но наверняка у тебя есть ошибки в ней (например таблицы `predmet` и `predmets`)

Comment: да я понимаю что реализация совсем плохая и не логический наименовал таблицы, вы на картинки новую таблицу создали?

Comment: нет, это результат запроса, который выше картинки, с помощью него мы получаем: айди предмета и группы, полное имя студента, его айди и балл по предмету. При желании можно еще добавить в запрос (в `select`) название предмета `select ..., predmet.name from ...`

Comment: Ошибка синтаксиса (пропущен оператор) в выражении запроса 'predmets.id = student.id INNER JOIN estimation ON predmets.id = estimation.id'

Comment: отредактируй вопрос, добавь туда SQL запрос который у тебя получился и сообщение об ошибке, я посмотрю

Comment: ```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT predmets.id_predmet, student.fullname, estimation.student_id, estimation.predmet_id, estimation.ball, predmets.id_course "+
"FROM predmets "+
"INNER JOIN "+
"student ON predmets.id = student.id "+
"INNER JOIN "+
"estimation ON predmets.id = estimation.id", db.GetConnection());
```
 Ошибка синтаксиса (пропущен оператор) в выражении запроса 'predmets.id = student.id INNER JOIN estimation ON predmets.id = estimation.id'

Comment: мой тебе совет, всегда когда выполняешь в коде в программе какой-то SQl запрос, выполни его сначала в СУБД (в access), проверь работает ли он и работает ли правильно и потом уже переноси в программу